# How to use values across Routes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have recently started to work on React, however I came across one issue. I have set up Routes, for different sites. Though in one of the classes, I have an Object, with given values. On the other hand, I have another class, where I want to fill out certain input fields with these values from the object. Is there a way, to use values across Routes?

Answer (score 0):

You can store the data in a store if you are using Flux, or in a state if using Redux. If you can share some more information about your project, I might be able to help with it better.